# How to create a list of increasing dates in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I am trying to create a list of 60 dates that increases by one day, each item, starting from the current date in flutter. But it isn't working it just stays on the current date.

My code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class UpComingPage extends StatefulWidget {
  UpComingPage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UpComingPageState createState() => _UpComingPageState();
}

class _UpComingPageState extends State<UpComingPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final items = List<DateTime>.generate(60, (i) {
      DateTime date = DateTime.utc(
        DateTime.now().year,
        DateTime.now().month,
        DateTime.now().day,
      );

      date.add(Duration(days: i));

      return date;
    });

    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          title: Text('Title'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return ListTile(
                title: Text('${items[index]}'),
              );
            },
            childCount: items.length,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should be returning `date.add(Duration(days: i))` since the [DateTime.add method](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/DateTime/add.html) doesn't actually modify the instance, but instead returns a new one with the changes made.

```dart
    final items = List<DateTime>.generate(60, (i) =>
      DateTime.utc(
        DateTime.now().year,
        DateTime.now().month,
        DateTime.now().day,
      ).add(Duration(days: i)));
```

Comment: So if I may ask, how would you fix it.

Comment: Edited the response with additional code. I made it more concise since it could be done in one line, but you could also have just changed `return date` to `return date.add(Duration(days: i));` in your existing code.